django rest-frame-work user_id related "violates not-null constraint"
I have this error
jango.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" of relation "defapp_actionlog" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, "{\"action\":\"push\"}", 2024-10-21 06:11:30.43758+00, 2024-10-21 06:11:30.43759+00, null).

What I want to do is push the actionlog from javascript and set the login user to model.
I set the CustomUser object to user row, however it still requies user_id?
my viewset,model,serializer is like this below.
class ActionLogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.ActionLog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.ActionLogSerializer
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        obj = serializer.save()
        return obj

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)   
        request.data._mutable = True
        request.data['user'] = m.CustomUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info(e)

        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)



class ActionLog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='action_user')
    detail = models.JSONField(default=dict,null=True, blank=True) 
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    
class ActionLogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True,source="actionlog_user")
    detail = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = m.ActionLog
        fields = ('id','user','detail')


Thanks to @Mohit Prajapat
I moved the def create to serializer from view, now it works well.
class ActionLogSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True,source="actionlog_user")
    detail = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = m.ActionLog
        fields = ('id','user','detail')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["user"] = self.context["request"].user
        obj = m.ActionLog.objects.create(**validated_data)
        obj.save()
        return obj


You are using ModalSerilizer here as I see, So you don't need to add id field explicitly in serializer. only the fields you want to customize should be there in serializer field while working with ModalSerilizer class

Thank you, I deleted id in serializer but situation doesn't change

Oh i got this you created serializer and explicitly added user field with read_only = True. and then update the create method in viewset. dont update create method in viewset update the create method of serializer,
def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["user"] = self.context["request"].user
        return super().create(validated_data)


It solves my problem perfectly, I updated the article . thank you very much!!

Also I Suggest to Not explicitly create the Object using django-orm use default super create method of serializers. as if you explicitly write the code then it is wrong as a senior  dev pov. because in drf everything is already created you just to need to update little.
You can refer my github repo for more details views and also connect me there mohit-trootech

OK, I will need to learn more further, I will check your github
